# Microsoft graph Java project - You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use microsoft graph api for a personal project however I cant seem to use a personal account for the login even though the tenant is set to "common" in the url which should allow for both organizational and personal microsoft accounts. would someone be able to explain why this restriction is so? I am not sure what adjustment I should make to resolve this

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fekbi.png)

[config on azure ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8hQU.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You’re sure you aren’t trying to access something that is work account only?

Answer (score 0):

The app registration you're using to authenticate is probably set not to allow personal accounts. Make sure it's set to either

- "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"
- "Personal Microsoft accounts only"